Why one of the following syntax work while the other doesnt (in C)
This like of code seems to give the correct result in Filter-more exercise in CS50.
int r = round(sqrt(pow(rgx, 2) + pow(rgy, 2)));
int g = round(sqrt(pow(ggx, 2) + pow(ggy, 2)));
int b = round(sqrt(pow(bgx, 2) + pow(bgy, 2)));
            if (r > 255)
            {
                r = 255;
            }
            if (g > 255)
            {
                g = 255;
            }
            if (b > 255)
            {
                b = 255;
            }
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = r;
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = g;
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = b;

But this code doesnt seem to work. Seems to Me that both codes are very similar.
copy[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sqrt(pow(rgx, 2) + pow(rgy, 2)));
copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sqrt(pow(ggx, 2) + pow(ggy, 2)));
copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sqrt(pow(bgx, 2) + pow(bgy, 2)));
            if (copy[i][j].rgbtRed > 255)
            {
                copy[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;
            }
            if (copy[i][j].rgbtGreen > 255)
            {
                copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = 255;
            }
            if (copy[i][j].rgbtBlue > 255)
            {
                copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;
            }


What does "Doesn't seem to work" mean??

Offtopic: don't do pow(rgx, 2) do rgx * rgx.

Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Look closely at the range of values that rgbtRed can hold.

Generally, don't use floating-point functions for integer arithmetic.

2 alternatives to int r = round(sqrt(pow(rgx, 2) + pow(rgy, 2))); --> int r = lroundf(hypotf(rgx, rgy));, int r = lroundf(sqrtf(1u*rgx*rgx, 1u*rgy*rgy));

@Someprogrammerdude: That is not appropriate advice here. The Sobel filter is not an “integer arithmetic” function.

Using the structure members directly, like copy[i][j].rgbtRed, fails because they are declared as eight-bit integers, like char, unsigned char, or uint8_t. So when round(sqrt(pow(rgx, 2) + pow(rgy, 2))) produces a result of 256 or greater, the value is lost. (The automatic conversion to uint8_t wraps it modulo 256.)
Then copy[i][j].rgbtRed > 255 is never true.
In contrast, the assignments to r, g, and b use the int type and hold the full calculated value until the clamping tests are performed.
